# fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/stash 2' (128)

Tags: ios, macos, git, synchronization, icloud

I am a new solo developer working on my first iOS app. I'm using Git for Mac to backup my progress and it's my first time using Git.

I'm developing the app across 2 laptops.

I also saved my Xcode project in my iCloud folder so that they would be synchronized across both macs.

Everything was working fine for the first 2 months, but I've come across this error on Git for Mac and I can no longer sync to Git nor revert to an older commit.

This is the error:

> fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/stash 2'  (128)

My guess is that an iCloud synchronization error happened between my macs and that messed up Git.

All I would like to do is be able to fix git so that I can recover my last working commit and then I will remove my project from iCloud to prevent this error from happening again.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the tree which is under your .git folder:
`tree .git` and check to see if you actually have this ref in your git filesystem.

If you want to reset your data (if you can) do `git reset HEAD --hard` it will reset your current branch to the latest commit.

---

### Some other solutions you can try as well

Make a backup of your repository since the  following commands are irreversible.

Search for the conflicted files and delete them
`find . -type f -name "* conflicted copy*" -exec rm -f {} \;`

lastly, remove any "conflicted" references from git's packed-refs file
`awk '!/conflicted/' .git/packed-refs > temp && mv temp .git/packed-refs`

Also take a look here (where the conflicts file may be in):

```
.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/
.git/logs/refs/heads/
.git/refs/remotes/origin/
.git/refs/heads/
```

Hope it will help you fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @jsexpert! I opened Terminal on Mac and navigated to my Xcode project file and tried `tree .git` and got `-bash: tree: command not found`. I tried `git reset HEAD --hard` and got `Reference has invalid format: 'refs/stash 2'`. I am now looking into how to backup my repository before trying the other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, git has identified the bad reference name already: it's `refs/stash 2` (with embedded space).  This probably won't be "packed" so it will just be a file with that name: `.git/refs/stash 2`.  Removing it should at worst lose one stash.  What *else* might be lurking, I have no idea; I don't let icloud (or dropbox or anything like that) touch my .git directories....

Comment: Thanks @torek So should I type this into Terminal? 
`git rm .git/refs/stash 2
git commit -m "remove .git/refs/stash 2"`

and yes-- I learned to never put my project files in a dropbox or iCloud folder from now on..

Comment: Not `git rm`, just plain `rm`.  Files inside the `.git` directory are git's internal state, asking git to do something with them is like trying to do your own appendectomy :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help @torek & @jsexpert! I removed the conflicted file as described and am able to use Git again. I lost a bunch of progress from the last week, but at least I am not starting from scratch, so thanks!

Comment: Update: I found a commit where my latest changes were, so no progress was lost. Tried the project and it was good as before. All good! Thanks!

Comment: If you deleted only `.git/refs/stash 2` file, then you shouldn't have lost any saved history (unless there was corruption elsewhere) -- you can try `git fsck --lost-found` or examine reflogs to find possible positions of deleted refs.